# How do I halve each item in a tuple quickly?

Tags: python, pygame, colors

I am using Python 3.3. Pygame uses tuples for colors. I need to halve each of the values in a tuple to make a darker color, but many times per second. I could use this function I wrote:

```
def halfTuple(oldTuple):
    newList = []
    for item in oldTuple:
        newList.append(item * .5)
    return tuple(newList)
```

but it might be slow. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Do you really need to do that several times per second, or can you precalculate it?

Comment: Nope... duh, I should have thought about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s likely that creating a new tuple from scratch instead of converting from an array will help:

```
def halfTuple(oldTuple):
    return tuple(x * 0.5 for x in oldTuple)
```